# Custom Form Property value keeps resetting at runtime

Tags: c#, forms, themes

I have a custom form which extends Form, and it overrides the OnPaint method to draw the form in a specific design using the Theme. I have a custom class "Theme" which contains four colors to set on the form:

```
public class Theme
{
    public Color BackColor { get; set; }
    public Color MouseHoverColor { get; set; }
    public Color ThemeColor { get; set; }
    public Color ForeColor { get; set; }
}
```

The theme has a custom UITypeEditor which uses a custom theme editor using color pickers, which I have tested and works fine:

```
public class ThemeTypeEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        var editor = new ThemeEditor((CustomForm) context.Instance);

        if (editor.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return editor.Theme;
        }

        return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
    }
}
```

I also have a static class "Themes" which contains a default theme for the form to use:

```
public static class Themes
{
    public static Theme DarkGreen = new Theme
    {
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(53, 53, 53),
        ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(237, 234, 235),
        MouseHoverColor = Color.FromArgb(65,65,65),
        ThemeColor = Color.FromArgb(32, 203, 88)
    };
}
```

And in my custom form, I have this property which is used by the OnPaint method:

```
private Theme theme = (Theme) Themes.DarkGreen;
[Category("Appearance"),
 Description("Specifies the Theme for this form."),
Editor(typeof(ThemeTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)),
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public Theme Theme {
    get { return theme; }
    set {
        theme = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to alter the theme in the designer on a new form which extends CustomForm, the designer does not update and the theme reverts to Themes.DarkGreen at runtime. I am unsure as to what I should be doing for this, as it is my understanding that I should be able to alter the theme and see the changes at design-time and runtime. As stated, the OnPaint method uses the Theme field above to draw the background color of the form and additional painted graphics. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The form in the form designer changes when the project is built and run, but the actual running form remains unchanged. I would like to have the changes be immediately visible when the theme is applied, and for it to be applied on the built application.

**EDIT 2:**

I decided to show a MessageBox to debug this. I placed one in my ThemeTypeEditor's EditValue method before it returned the new theme, and sure enough, it works, and the theme values are correct. However, I also placed a MessageBox in my Theme Property setter, after Invalidate();, and nothing shows. It's like the property's set isn't being called at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing various things. The first was creating a base class named ComponentBase which extends Component and implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class ComponentBase : Component, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;

        var changeService = GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService)) as IComponentChangeService;
        if (changeService != null)
            changeService.OnComponentChanged(this, TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this).Find(propertyName, false), field, value);

        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        return true;
    }
}
```

This meant that I needed to remove the Auto-Property nature of the properties of my Theme. I changed the Editor of each Color in the Theme so that it used the color picker, and gave them a DesignerSerializationVisibility of Visible:

```
public sealed partial class Theme : ComponentBase
{
    private Color backgroundColor;

    [Category("Theme")]
    [DisplayName("Background Color")]
    [Editor(typeof (ThemeTypeEditor), typeof (UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof (ThemeColorConverter))]
    public Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return backgroundColor; }
        set { SetField(ref backgroundColor, value); }
    }

    private Color foregroundColor;

    [Category("Theme")]
    [DisplayName("Foreground Color")]
    [Editor(typeof(ThemeTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ThemeColorConverter))]
    public Color ForegroundColor
    {
        get { return foregroundColor; }
        set { SetField(ref foregroundColor, value); }
    }

    private Color highlightColor;

    [Category("Theme")]
    [DisplayName("Highlight Color")]
    [Editor(typeof(ThemeTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ThemeColorConverter))]
    public Color HighlightColor
    {
        get { return highlightColor; }
        set { SetField(ref highlightColor, value); }
    }

    private Color borderColor;

    [Category("Theme")]
    [DisplayName("Border Color")]
    [Editor(typeof(ThemeTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ThemeColorConverter))]
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return borderColor; }
        set { SetField(ref borderColor, value); }
    }

    private Color themeColor;

    [Category("Theme")]
    [DisplayName("Theme Color")]
    [Editor(typeof(ThemeTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ThemeColorConverter))]
    public Color ThemeColor
    {
        get { return themeColor; }
        set { SetField(ref themeColor, value); }
    }
}
```

As the Theme in my custom form uses DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content, this allows code to be generated for the contents of the Theme, meaning that the individual colors in the Theme are updated both design-time and run-time:

```
private Theme theme;

[DisplayName("Theme")]
[Category("Appearance")]
[Description("Specifies the Theme for this form.")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public Theme Theme
{
    get { return theme; }
    set
    {
        theme = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```